# Html Profile Card

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a tab in my html site. When you click on the tab named "Profile"; it will bring up a page that will display a Profile Card. With this card it displays your picture, what is your job, what languages you know, and a message button.

I have my code. But what I am trying to figure out is. How do I make it so the user is able to change there profile card? Like if they wanna changes what languages they know or there profile card picture.

My code so far:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <style>
    .card {
        box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        max-width: 300px;
        margin: auto;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: arial;
    }
    
    .title {
        color: grey;
        font-size: 18px;
    }
    
    button {
        border: none;
        outline: 0;
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 8px;
        color: white;
        background-color: #000;
        text-align: center;
        cursor: pointer;
        width: 100%;
        font-size: 18px;
    }
    
    a {
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 22px;
        color: black;
    }
    
    button:hover,
    a:hover {
        opacity: 0.7;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <h2 style="text-align:center">User Profile Card</h2>
    <div class="card">
        <img src="IMAGE" alt="IMAGE HERE" style="width:100%">
        <h1>Name Here</h1>
        <p class="title">What is your job</p>
        <p>What programming languages you know</p>
        <div style="margin: 24px 0;">
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-comments-o"></i></a>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Your question shows no attempt at implementing the functionality you are asking about. Stack Overflow is not a coding service. You are expected to research your issue and make a good attempt to write the code yourself before posting.

Answer (score 0):

Simply give input fields and design them like they are paragraphs with CSS. Remove their border if you want.

Hope [This link](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_login_form.asp) will work for you and will give you new ways to think creatively. Change this code as you like.

Answer (score 0):

> Following code might help you

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <style>
    .card {
        box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        max-width: 300px;
        margin: auto;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: arial;
    }
    
    .title {
        color: grey;
        font-size: 18px;
    }
    
    button {
        border: none;
        outline: 0;
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 8px;
        color: white;
        background-color: #000;
        text-align: center;
        cursor: pointer;
        width: 100%;
        font-size: 18px;
    }
    
    a {
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 22px;
        color: black;
    }
    
    button:hover,
    a:hover {
        opacity: 0.7;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <h2 style="text-align:center">User Profile Card</h2>
    <div class="card">
<h2>Fill in the information below:</h2>
        <!-- <img src="IMAGE" alt="IMAGE HERE" style="width:100%">-->
        
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div style="margin: 10px 0;text-align:center;">
          <input type="file" class="title" style="font-size: 16px;width: 68%;"> 
        </div>
        <div style="margin: 10px 0;text-align:center;">
          <input type="text" class="title" placeholder="Your name here">
        </div>

        <div style="margin: 10px 0;text-align:center;">
          <input type="text" class="title" placeholder="What is your job">
        </div>

        <div style="margin: 10px 0;text-align:center;">
        <select name="language" style="height: 32px;">
          <option value="">Choose programming language</option>
          <option value="node-js">Node.js</option>
          <option value="angular-js">Angular.js</option>
        </select>
        </div>
        </form>
        <div style="margin: 24px 0;">
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-comments-o"></i></a>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you Mohit! This helps me greatly! Now I am just going to add in a save and edit button! What code would you say to add in a image by a user?

Comment: Glad you liked it, I am gonna edit my answer and add the input type file for submitting profile image.

Answer (score -1):

Use HTML content-editable fields (div's) in card display itself. Provide a Save button and a Cancel Button in the card itself, if user changes any field in card. And original values are different from current values. For Image, you can provide a Upload URL modal pop-up, and then update the link in the card post image upload.